# Store time in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, local-storage, array-push

I'm trying to push a lapsed time to local storage. Whenever the user clicks a submit button a clock stops and a duration is calculated. I want to push that duration time to an array in local storage. And after the last click I want to fetch the entire array to calculate the total time. There are several similar questions in SO but none of them siuts this purpose fully. I can see in my local storage that an array with key: 'Time' has been created but it isn't populating.
Code:

```
let answerButton = document.querySelector('#send')
answerButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  TotalTime.stop()
  TotalTime.duration()
  clearTimeout(window.countdownTimer)
  timer()
  let totalTime = []
  TotalTime.duration().push(window.localStorage.setItem('Time', JSON.stringify(totalTime)))
})
```

Comment: Where does `TotalTime` come from? You appear to just set it as an empty array... Also, `TotalTime` !== `totalTime`.

Comment: You have to populate the javascript array...then stringify it to set in localStorage

Comment: @charlietfl So I should push to a normal array and then send the whole array to local storage, stringified?

Comment: Also `localStorage.setItem()` [does not return anyting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem#Return_value). So you are pushing `undefined` into `.duration()`.

Comment: Yes...that is the process for storing an array or object in a single storage key

Comment: @charlietfl Nice, even easier... Then I could just push the calculated total time to local storage... Thanks